# browser back issue with javascript disable submit until checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, form-submit

I've tried a few but similar ways of disabling a form submit button until a checkbox is checked.

`<input type="checkbox" name="toc" value="accept" onclick="formsubmit.disabled = !this.checked" >I accept`

`<input class="FontSans" type="submit" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit" value="submit" disabled="disabled" >`

However if after submission you need to go back in the browser then the form shows the checkbox as checked but the submit is disabled. To enable the submit you need to uncheck
and check. Is there a way round this?

Comment: You need to run something in the document's `onload` handler to enable or disable as appropriate.

Comment: thanks, went the jquery route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're using jQuery or not, but here's a jQuery-centric solution.

```
jQuery(function() {
  if ($('.check').is(':checked')) {
    $('form').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('form').attr('disabled', true);
  }
})
```

Let me know if you need vanilla JS.

Answer (score -1):

This should prevent browser from restoring previous state

```
<input ... autocomplete="off" />
```